# How to choose the right picture size

Tags: android

Hy!

I have two pictures on the view and a button at the buttom.

But the Problem is that the last picture is drawn at the button and not under the first on. So the button at the buttom is unvisible.

[image: Screenshot]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mainscreen" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Selected Channel" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mainscreen_state"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageAd" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageView> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainscreen_btchange" 
        android:text="Change State"></Button>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainscreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Selected Channel"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainscreen_state"></TextView>
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ImageAd"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Change State"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/mainscreen_btchange"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>

  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

*you open the RelativeLayout in the wrong place, so that the only thing inside is the Button
you should put it before and use some `android:layout_below` attributes to choose the right position for all the elements*

there are many ways to create a layout, if you want to use a RelativeLayout you have to use it the right way. the right way is to put inside it 2 or more Views and tell by using the attribute `android:layout_below` or similar attributes where is the position of one object in a relative way to the other.

for example you want the first image *over* the second? you have put them in the same relative layout and put in the second image an attribute `android:layout_below="@id/1st_image_id"`

Comment: the rl is needed to get the button at the bottom

Comment: i have uptaded my answer to be more specific, maybe the first one was not so clear